# Writing rules in Drools without using sailence -- checking not exists

Tags: drools

**I am trying to write rules avoiding ordering. The scenario I have is --**

```
rule "common rule"
when
 // check if it is a "xyz" customer
then
  insertLogical(new MyCondition("Is a xyz customer", true));
end
```

In the other rules, I make decisions based on above condition --

```
rule "rule1"
when
 MyCondition("Is a xyz customer", true)
then
 System.out.println("This is a xyz customer");
end
```

I have another rule --

```
rule "rule2"
when
 not MyCondition("Is a xyz customer", true)
then
 System.out.println("This is NOT a xyz customer");
end
```

As I am not using any sailence, in some cases, both my rule1 and rule2 are getting fired. Initially, there is no MyCondition object in knowledgebase, "rule2" is getting fired. Later, an object for MyCondition is being inserted and "rule1" is getting fired.

**1. When I don't have rules that check "not" condition, everything works perfectly. I am having problems when I use the "not" exists condition. What are the ways to overcome this?**

Comment: did you ever find a better approach to this issue? I'd be keen to hear from other solution that don't rely on using salience.

Answer (score 1):

> "I am trying to write rules avoiding ordering"

It sounds like you need to order your rules using salience in order to get the desired behavior.

I suggest that you use a higher salience on the rule(s) that insert a "MyCondition" fact than the rules that check for the presence or absence of a "MyCondition" fact.

For example:

```
rule "common rule"
salience 10
  when
    // check if it is a "xyz" customer
  then
    insertLogical(new MyCondition("Is a xyz customer", true));
end
```

```
rule "rule1"
salience 0
when
 MyCondition("Is a xyz customer", true)
then
 System.out.println("This is a xyz customer");
end
```

```
rule "rule2"
salience 0
when
 not MyCondition("Is a xyz customer", true)
then
 System.out.println("This is NOT a xyz customer");
end
```

Comment: Thanks mikedev9000 for the answer.  Sure, using salience is one of the solutions. I am more interested in solutions that don't use salience. what are the best practices to write rules that are modular and reusable?